How not scroll position after re render screen React native
How to stop ScrollView position changing after rendering the whole page. I have a ScrollView component of vertical scrolling of an online store. There are also nested FlatLists with product tiles, they have buttons for adding to cart, favorites and others. Each tile is dynamic and scrolls horizontally inside the FlatList. After clicking "Add to cart", the element inside the FlatList is redrawn and the position of the parent ScrollView is reset. FlatList elements can also be updated from another screen, from the cart itself, so I pass the render function of this screen to other screens. I tried to get the Y position. But after rendering, the function for getting the position is called and Y becomes 0. I also tried to change the data by passing it to the FlatList component.
<KeyboardAwareScrollView
keyboardShouldPersistTaps= 'always'>

<FlatList
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        horizontal
        data={products}
        renderItem={({item}) => 
            <View >
            {renderAddOrDeleteProductToBasket(item)}
            </View>
        </View>
        }/>

I try extraData={reRenderThisComponent}, try save scroll positon

Are you using redux to manage the cart?

No, i don't used redux

Assuming all normal reactjs functionality is sustained within expo the following should help.
Using only React I would suggest adding a listener to the window that saves the scrollPosition into sessionStorage prior to unloading and when we load back in we can get that scrollPosition from our storage and apply it. We can handle this all within a useEffect so the scroll position is checked once upon loading of the app, along with the listener being added once upon loading. The following should achieve this behavior.
useEffect(()=>{
 const scrollPosition = sessionStorage.getItem('scrollPosition');
 if(scrollPosition){
  window.scrollTo(0, parseInt(scrollPosition)
 }
 
 const handleUnload = () => {
  sessionStorage.setItem('scrollPosition', window.scrollY);
 }
 window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleUnload);
 
 return () => {
  window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleUnload);
 }
}, [])

Not completely sure on the syntax but this should work. Let me know if any of this doesn't make sense or if you need further clarification.
EDIT: After some research it seems most of this functionally does not exist in react-native. Here is an altered version with the same methodology.
First we need to add a ScrollView around everything on this page, below is the params you will need to pass into it.
<ScrollView
  ref={scrollViewRef}
  onScroll={handleScroll}
  scrollEventThrottle={16}
>

The handleScroll function passed into the ScrollView is this:
const handleScroll = (event) => {
 setScrollY(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
};

The following will save our scrollY anytime is changes and when the component dismounts.
useEffect(() => {
return () => {
    localStorage.setItem('scrollPosition', scrollY.toString());
  };
}, [scrollY]);

Here is the rest of the code we will need:
const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState(0);
const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);
useEffect(()=>{
 const storedScrollY = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('scrollPosition') || '0');
 if(storedScrollY){
  scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ y: storedScrollY, animated: false });
 }
}, []);


This would help if not for the architecture. Requiring the state and other components of the screen to be re-rendered when it is opened, so I use useFocusEffect. It in turn starts the re-render and then runs the function
onScroll={handleScroll}
which in turn will start saving the Y=0 coordinate and reset the saved state in storage or in a static variable. Is it possible to somehow change the architecture of the component?

Not so sure about changing the architecture but instead some kind of block that prevents it from overriding the localStorage until you have accessed it once, you could have a boolean variable the setting of the localStorage depends on and have the useEffect that fetches it set it to true? Not completely sure though, my native experience is minimal unfortunately
